# Sorting based on Future Result

Tags: list, scala, sorting, future

I've trying to sort a list by a future boolean.

I have a list of IDs and I need to query an external service to find out if there's contextual information behind them. The method I use to do this returns an optional future.

By using the partition method I hoped to create two lists of IDs, one with contextual information and one without.

The following answer on here provided a lot of help for this: [Scala - sort based on Future result predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537893/scala-sort-based-on-future-result-predicate/30540548#30540548)

I now have an rough, untested method that looks like so,

```
val futureMatch = listOfIds.map( b => b.map{ j =>
  getContext(j).map{ k =>
    Map( j -> k)
  }
}).map(Future.sequence(_)).flatMap(identity)

val partitionedList = futureMatch.map(_.partition{
  case (k, Some(v)) => true
  case _ => false
})
```

So as advised in the other question, I'm attempting to get all my answers at the same level, and then using `Future.sequence` and `flatMap(identity)` to flatten nested layers of futures.

The problem is this doesn't feel very efficient.

Ideally the successful list would have a signature of `List[Map[String, String]]` not `List[Map[String, Option[String]]` and the failed list would just be a list of Strings, so it'd only need to be one dimensional. As it currently stands I have two identical list signatures which have some redundancy. For example in the successful list, I know this is going exist so it doesn't need to be an option.

Any ideas how I could achieve this structure and produce two lists with different signatures or even if this is the most efficient way.

Thanks.

EDIT: Looking at the signature for partition it looks like I can only produce two lists of the same signature, so a different signature is probably too much to ask. I guess I can just flatten the list afterwards.

Comment: What's `listOfIds`? Can you provide an example from the REPL?

Comment: `listOfIds: List[Object] = List(Map(d -> 1, e -> 2), a, b, c)`

Comment: `List[Object]` is a dangerous type as you know nothing about the `List`'s elements at compile-time. You can definitely do better than resorting to `List[Object]`.

Comment: Good point. I'm constructing the list myself so I can make it anything. I guess the unmatched types could still be a map, with an optional value. The whole list could be this. Hmmm. The containing list is also pretty redundant when I think about it. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score -1):

I found a suitable solution in the comments of the question I linked too.

```
val (matched, unmatched) =
  finalMatch.foldLeft(List.empty[Map[String, String]], List.empty[String]) {
     case ((matched, unmatched), p) => p match {
       case m:Map[String, String] => (m :: matched, unmatched)
       case s:String => (matched, s :: unmatched)
     }
   }
```

The only issue with this is it leads to type erasure. I've opened another question to discuss this issue.

[Dealing with Type Erasure with foldLeft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514301/dealing-with-type-erasure-with-foldleft)

Thanks all.