# Dealing with Type Erasure with foldLeft

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I have a list that contains a mixture of strings and maps, `listOfIds`. The code below attempts to this list. Maps into matched and strings to unmatched.

```
val (matched, unmatched) =
  listOfIds.foldLeft(List.empty[Map[String, String]], List.empty[String]) {
     case ((matched, unmatched), p) => p match {
       case m:Map[String, String] => (m :: matched, unmatched)
       case s:String => (matched, s :: unmatched)
     }
   }
```

The issue is I'm running into type erasure. I found that I was able to use place holders for the types to get around this `m:Map[_, _]`,but this causes issues later on when attempting to extract the map values.

I'm unfamiliar with type tags but quick research suggests that this could be a solution... Would appreciate any points how I could get around type erasure in this instance.

Thanks!

Comment: You can find a solution to your `type erasure` problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete . `foldLeft` might not be the optimal method here. Did you have a look at `partition` in the `Seq`-Trait , this looks like a good fit?

Comment: The issue with partition is that the returns lists have the same signature. I suppose this isn't the worst issue, as I'd just need to flatten it but still. Thanks for the link, I'll see what I can throw together now.

Comment: What is the type of `listOfIds`?

Comment: Atm it's `List[Object]`

Comment: What error are you getting? Seems to work for me ...